# Edit Item Ribbon disappears on DispForm.ASPX

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, display-form

I have a custom list and I have full admin rights to the entire site. I can click on the Title (linked) item within the list, and it takes me to the DispForm.aspx, and the Ribbon shows properly. This ribbon includes:

- "Edit Item"
- "Shared With"
- "Delete Item"
  Etc.

When I am logged in with a user than only has edit rights to the subsite this list is in, the list itself, and the page I have the listview webpart in, and I click on the Title (linked) item, I am taken to the dispform.aspx. But this time there is no Edit Item, or even a ribbon at all.

I have tried playing with the permissions of this users and cannot seem to figure out what the issue is. I do not believe it is a master page issue since I am able to see the ribbon fine when I am logged in as myself with full admin rights.

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: can you please check and let us know if the list is inheriting permissions from the site or the permissions are broken on the list?

Comment: Amit, the permissions for the list are not inherited, I caused them to have their own permissions.

Comment: Caleb, Can you please check if the user is having required permission on the list since permissions for the list are not inherited.

Comment: Amit, yes, correct permissions on the list as well.